# WSO2 Service Provider and Identity Provider login to API Store/Publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

### The Problem

Right now when a user tries to login to the default wso2 API Store/Publisher. It wont authorize the user so it tries to login in then will log out right away, in the store. In the publisher it will throw a 401 Unauthorized error. I found a quick fix which was in the carbon I added a user to the role application/API Store and application/API Publisher and now that user can login. I'm guessing either the SP or the IdP isn't getting the roles right on the user.
There are no errors to find, but logging in causes the logs in API Manager to say this

```
 INFO {org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso.SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject} -  invalidate: Session already invalidated {org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso.SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject}
```

### Environment

Our environment is a cluster environment with the identity server 5.2 as the key manager. Also we got the API manager 2.0 and some gateway workers. We use federated authentication SAML2 over to shibboleth, all of that seems to be working fine.

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this problem or maybe help me understand the user roles and permissions better within wso2 would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got login in to work by adding the permissions login and API(subscribe, create, publish) to the internal/everyone role.

Comment: I did the same for specific roles I needed. worked.